# Change scientific notation to decimal in php array

Tags: php

I fetch the csv data using file_get_contents() and explode to make an array

i got array

my code

```
<?php

    $csvcontent = file_get_contents($url);
    $csv_array = explode($lineseparator,$csvcontent); 
    $csv_array = array_filter($csv_array);

?>
```

I got array

```
 Array ( [0] => 2018-06-03,4477651688.19,163280,1.30288e+11,7632.09,4851760000.0,2037.5,15.3074038,531463,4.30694957398e+12,285966,246.271822195,1.356e-05,
         [1] => 2018-06-04,7925996820.24,209733,1.31847e+11,7722.53,4993170000.0,2287.5,20.71075272,702904,4.30694957398e+12,341314,310.568030875,1.373e-05,
         [2] => 2018-06-05,5821973644.02,212726,1.28081e+11,7500.9,4961740000.0,2187.5,18.52827963,655694,4.41559334167e+12,348466,305.3316354,1.531e-05
 )
```

How to change the scientic notation to decimal in php array

original number in csv is 0.00001356 . whilw i get using file_get_contents() . i got  1.356e-05.
whil i use (float) $num or ($num + 0) it gives 1.356E-05. i need full number 0.00001356

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to split the string and get the scientific number. Then you can convert.

PHP is dynamically typed. Try subtracting zero from the value. It'll convert the data type for you.

```
$val = '1.30288e+11';
$result = $val - 0;

echo "String: $val Number: $result";
```

You'll get the output

```
String: 1.30288e+11 Number: 130288000000
```

Comment: still not working Array ( [0] => 2018-06-03 [1] => 4477651688.19 [2] => 163280 [3] => 130288000000 [4] => 7632.09 [5] => 4851760000 [6] => 2037.5 [7] => 15.3074038 [8] => 531463 [9] => 4306949573980 [10] => 285966 [11] => 246.271822195 [12] => 1.356E-5 )

Comment: I use the same way you prefer. But "1.356e-05" change to "1.356E-05". not decimal value

Comment: for($j=0;$j<count($linearray);$j++)
  {
   if($j > 0)
   {
    //~ $linearray[$j] = (string) $linearray[$j];
    $linearray[$j] = ($linearray[$j] + 0);
   }
    
  }
  
  print_r($linearray); exit; using like this but not work